# Explain ipaddress assignment to the virtual box?

Tags: linux, virtualbox

presently my subnet ipaddress starts with 192.168.0.XXX. now my quetion is I am using virtual box in that i installed  ubuntu 14.04 can i assign the ipaddress of the node with diffrent ipaddress EX:192.168.1.XXX??

Answer (score 2):

As I remember, in VirtualBox you have at least two options for the virtual network interface:

- NAT
- Bridged

If the subnet of the **host** is 192.168.0.XXX, and the **virtual** is 192.168.1.XXX ( or simply, different subnet) then the virtual card must be using *NAT*.

If you want to use *Bridge* then the subnet of the **host**  must be the same of the  **virtual**.

When do you need to use one or the other?

Bridge will make it looks as if the virtual machine is in the same LAN as the host.

NAT will make the VM more isolated, able to navigate on internet but hardly to reach from LAN (you will need to open specific ports).